# DialogflowCX Parameters Get Set Page Transition Does Not Occur

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Playing around with DialogflowCX and I am running into an issue where it appears their logic processor is simply broken. Oddly I have something similar in a previous page that works, but it is only checking 2 params. I have also tried page, session, and intent params with no luck on any of them. What am I missing here? How can I read the logs to see why it thinks something is null?

[image: Image of DialogflowCX UI]

The line cut off on the left is $intent.params.contact-address-line

EDIT I actually tested with simply true and yet still does not progress to next page. No response is given back either. I tried a separate route with $page.params.status = 'FINAL' and then true and still nothing. It finishes gathering the parameters and is done.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `$session.params` instead of `$intent.params`.

> Oddly I have something similar in a previous page that works, but it is only checking 2 params.

Possibly it worked because you were providing both parameters (entities) in the same utterance. When you capture the address, you ask multiple questions
and a new match is performed every time. `$intent.params` only applies to the last intent matched.

In this example, the route is only evaluated if both entities are provided in the same utterance (the 3rd attempt).
[image]

The intent definition:
[image]

See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#intent-ref)

Doc says this:

> Note: Due to the short-lived lifespan of intent parameter values, it is usually recommended to use session parameter references instead of intent parameter references.

Regarding debugging:

> How can I read the logs to see why it thinks something is null?

The logs don't go into this level of details. You can always have a route defined before your other route (don't forget to use the same intent) that outputs the content of the parameters you are interested in:
[image]

Comment: "I have also tried page, session, and intent params with no luck on any of them."

Comment: I do appreciate the response. Ultimately after a lot of debugging I found that it wasn't the true or falseness of this that was at fault, seems like the page just crashed honestly. I deleted everything and started over with an identical flow and page setup and it worked again. Guessing something funky happened with the old version.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$session.params` or `$page.params` instead of `$intent.params`.